# Is the equation $\vec{B}=\mu\vec{H}$ correct in general? How shall we derive it?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

The relation between magnetic flux density $(\vec{B})$ and magnetic field intensity $(\vec{H})$, in general, is:

\begin{equation}
\vec{B}=\mu_0(\vec{H}+\vec{M})
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

One of my colleagues told equation (1) can be written as:

\begin{equation}
\vec{B}=\mu\vec{H}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $\mu$ is the permeability of the medium.

**Is this correct in general? If yes, how can we derive $(2)$ from $(1)$?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magnetization is gained as a result of an external magnetic field applied, so there must be a relation between the two vectors (i.e. a transformation) that takes the form of a tensor function. This transformation is known as the magnetic susceptibility.

Your equation $\mathbf{B} = \mu \mathbf{H}$ is only correct in linear homogeneous isotropic magnetic materials. "Linear" means that the magnetization is in the same direction as the magnetic field (i.e. the tensor function reduces to a scalar function), "homogeneous" means that the susceptibility is the same throughout, and "isotropic" means that susceptibility is the same in all directions. **So, to answer your question, it is not correct in general.** Most materials, however, *do* behave in this way when the applied magnetic field is not too strong.

In such a material, the magnetization is directly proportional to the applied magnetic field: $$\mathbf{M} = \chi_m \mathbf{H}$$ where $\chi_m$ is the magnetic susceptibility. So we have $$\mathbf{B} = \mu_0 (\mathbf{H} + \mathbf{M}) = \mu_0 (1 + \chi_m) \mathbf{H} = \mu \mathbf{H}$$ The quantity $(1 + \chi_m)$ is known as the *relative permeability*.