# Understanding $\textbf{M} = \chi \textbf{H}$

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Suppose I have a linear homogeneous isotropic magnetic material, such that
$$\textbf{M} = \chi \textbf{H}\tag{1},$$ where $\chi$ is the magnetic susceptibility, $\textbf{M}$ the magnetization, and $\textbf{H}$ is the magnetic field.

In some articles/webpages, for exemple [[1]](http://www.mri-q.com/what-is-susceptibility-chi.html), [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_susceptibility) and  [[3]](http://www.mri-q.com/uploads/3/4/5/7/34572113/susceptibility_of_inorganic_compounds.pdf), equation $(1)$ says how the material is magnetized when it is placed in an **external** magnetic field $\textbf{H}$ .

However, in [Jackson's book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Classical-Electrodynamics-John-David-Jackson/dp/047130932X) and in [this article](https://www.academia.edu/27019747/Electrostatics_and_Magnetostatics_of_Polarized_Ellipsoidal_Bodies_The_Depolarization_Tensor_Method) (page 64), the magnetic field $\textbf{H}$ is the one inside the material, not an external field.

I always thought the correct $\textbf{H}$-field in equation $(1)$ is inside the material, because it leads to $\textbf{B}=\mu_{0}(\textbf{H}+\textbf{M}) \implies \textbf{B}=\mu_{0}(\textbf{H}+ \chi\textbf{H}) \implies \textbf{B}=\mu\textbf{H},$ where $\mu$ is the permeability of the material.

But I am really confused about what field I should use (internal or external) in equation $(1)$ because of the first three references.

Why some authors use $\textbf{H}$ as the applied field and others the internal field? For the former, is it a kind of approximation?

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: The $\bf{H}$ in $\bf{M}=\chi \bf{H}$ is what you call the *internal* field not the *applied* field. The two fields, internal and applied are the same for a coil tightly wound over a ferromagnetic toroid core.

Comment: @hyportnex, Ok, but why lot of authors use $\textbf{H}$ as the applied field? See the references that I cited and also [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/428830/is-the-equation-vecb-mu-vech-correct-in-general-how-shall-we-derive-it/428831#428831). I can cite several other articles if we want. I don't understand. Is it a kind of approximation? :(

Comment: Th external or better called *applied* field and the internal field are linearly related in a *linear isotropic* material, a "soft magnet". What your reference *this answer* says is wrong in general but correct for a toroid. The difference between the two fields, applied and internal, is usually called the *demagnetization* field and is caused by surface poles of which there are none in the case of a toroid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Lots of authors" are very careless.  The external applied ${\bf H}$ is only the same as the internal ${\bf H}$ for samples that are long and thin and oriented parallel to the external field.   Direct measurements of $\chi$ use samples of this shape for this reason. Any other shape requires computations of demagnetizing factors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demagnetizing_field.

One can get away with ignoring the demagnetizing effect when $\chi$ is small, as it often is. Hence the confusing discussions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A side question: if the material is ferromagnetic (in this case $\textbf{M}=\chi^{(d)}\textbf{H}$, where $\chi^{(d)}$ is the differential susceptibility), do we need to compute the demagnetizing field to obtain $\textbf{M}$?

Comment: So is Jackson right (as always) or not in this case?